# Lettrine Not Keeping Up with the Size of the Font

Tags: pdftex, lettrine, drop-cap

Consider the following code and output:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\begin{document}
\small
  \lettrine{M}{ore} words. Again more words. Again more words. Again more words. Again more words. Again more words. Again more words. Again more words.

\vskip 15pt

\large
  \lettrine{M}{ore} words. Again more words. Again more words. Again more words. Again more words. Again more words. Again more words. Again more words.
  
\vskip 15pt    

\LARGE
    \lettrine{M}{ore} words. Again more words. Again more words. Again more words. Again more words. Again more words. Again more words. Again more words.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice that as the font size increases from small to large to Large, the size of the drop cap remains the name---forcing it lower and lower into the paragraph (not aesthetically pleasing).

QUESTION: (i) How may this be corrected so that the appearance of the last two paragraphs are similar (relatively speaking) to the first? (ii) Is there to override the default and increase the height of the lettrine should one want to?

Thank you.

Comment: This isn't directly releated to lettrine, just the available sizes for the font.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Latex warns you

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmr/m/n' in size <56.09955> not available
(Font)              size <24.88> substituted on input line 15.
```

If you use `fix-cm` package so cm is available at any size (or use more or less any font set other than computer modern, I use latin modern here) then

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\small
  \lettrine{M}{ore} words. Again more words. Again more words. Again more words. Again more words. Again more words. Again more words. Again more words.

\vskip 15pt

\large
  \lettrine{M}{ore} words. Again more words. Again more words. Again more words. Again more words. Again more words. Again more words. Again more words.
  
\vskip 15pt    

\LARGE
    \lettrine{M}{ore} words. Again more words. Again more words. Again more words. Again more words. Again more words. Again more words. Again more words.
\end{document}
```